# How to crop the roi of the image

Tags: opencv, crop, roi

in my project I want to crop the ROI of an image. For this I create a map with the regions of interesst. Now I want to crop the area which has the most important pixels (black is not important, white is important).

Has someone an idea how to realize it? I think this is a maximazion problem
The red border in the image below is an example how I want to crop this image 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you have computed a value at every point in the image. These values suggests the "importance"/"interestingness"/"saliency" of each point. The matrix/image containing these values is the "map" you are referring to. Your goal is to get the bounding box for regions of interests (ROI) with high "importance" score.

The way I think you can go about segmenting the ROIs is to apply Graph Cut based segmentation computing a "score" at each pixel using your importance map. The result of the segmentation is a binary mask that masks the "important" pixels. Next, run OpenCV's [findcontours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontour#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20OutputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29) function on this binary mask to get the individual connected components. Then use OpenCV's [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#Rect%20boundingRect%28InputArray%20points%29) function on the contours returned by findContours(...) to get the bounding boxes.

The good thing about using a Graph Cut based segmentation algorithm in this way is that it will join up fragmented components i.e. the resulting binary mask will tend not to have pockets of small holes even if your "importance" map is noisy.

One Graph Cut based segmentation algorithm already implemented in OpenCV is the GrabCut algorithm. A quick hack would be to apply it on your "importance" map to get the binary mask I mentioned above. A more sophisticated approach would be to build the foreground and background (color perhaps?) model using your "importance" map and passing it as input to the function. More details on GrabCut in OpenCV can be found here: [http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=grabcut#void grabCut(InputArray img, InputOutputArray mask, Rect rect, InputOutputArray bgdModel, InputOutputArray fgdModel, int iterCount, int mode)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=grabcut#void%20grabCut%28InputArray%20img,%20InputOutputArray%20mask,%20Rect%20rect,%20InputOutputArray%20bgdModel,%20InputOutputArray%20fgdModel,%20int%20iterCount,%20int%20mode%29)

If you would like greater flexibility, you can hack your own graphcut based segmentation algorithm using the following MRF library. This library allows you to specify your custom objective function in computing the graph cut: http://vision.middlebury.edu/MRF/code/

To use the MRF library, you will need to specify the "cost" at each point in your image indicating whether that point is "foreground" or "background". You can also think of this dichotomy as "important" or "not important" instead of "foreground" vs "background". 
The MRF library's goal is to return you a label at each point such that total cost of assigning those labels is as small as possible. Hence, the game is to come up with a function to compute a small cost for points you consider important and large otherwise.

Specifically, the cost at each point is composed of 2 parts: 1) The data term/function and 2) The smoothness term/function. As mentioned earlier, the smaller the data term at each point, the more likely that point will be selected. If your "importance" score s_ij is in the range [0, 1], then a common way to compute your data term would be -log(s_ij).

The smoothness terms is a way to suggest whether 2 neighboring pixels p, q, should have the same label i.e. both "foreground", "background", or one "foreground" and the other "background". Similar to the data cost, you have to construct it such that the cost is small for neighbor pixels having similar "importance" score so that they will be assigned the same label. This term is responsible for "smoothing" the resulting mask so that you will not have pixels of low "importance" sprinkled within regions of high "importance" and vice versa. If there are such regions, OpenCV's findContours(...) function mentioned above will return contours for these regions, which can be filtered out perhaps by checking their size.

Details on functions to compute the cost can be found in the GrabCut paper: [GrabCut](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67890/paper_siggraph04.pdf&ei=zErAUP3qKY3OrQfO-YGQDQ&usg=AFQjCNGYrPEjrR-yGbBv7Tn1qPyZuxqDZg)

This blog post provides a bit more detail (and code) on creating your own graphcut segmentation algorithm in OpenCV: http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/05/05/bust-out-your-own-graphcut-based-image-segmentation-with-opencv-w-code/

Another paper showing how to perform graph cut segmentation on grayscale images (your case), with better notations, and without the complicated image matting part (not implemented in OpenCV's version) in the GrabCut paper is this: [Graph Cuts and Efficient N-D Image Segmentation](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http://lvelho.impa.br/ip12/reading/ijcv06.pdf&ei=P2zAUN2-NcfJrAeAkYCAAQ&usg=AFQjCNHBXkpQ-nurYgs2OitQS3naWbLgrw)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I could favourite an answer..., +1.